# $n$ is a positive integer, if whenever $n$ divide $ab$, $n$ also divide $a$ or a divide $b$, then n is a prime.

Tags: number-theory

The title has proved as below, but I don't understand the proof.
Assume $n$ is not a prime, then $n$ has nontrivial divisor, $a|n$, $1<a<n$, and then $n = ab$, $1<b<n$, but then $n|ab$, and $n$ not divide $a$ and not divide $b$, contradiction. Any help thanks!

Comment: Composite  $ab\mid ab$. Does it divide $a$ or $b$?

Comment: But why $a|n$? Isn't it assume $n|a$? And why $n=ab$?

Comment: The contrapositive of "$P(n)\,\Rightarrow\, p\ $ prime" is "$p\,$ not prime $\,\Rightarrow\, \lnot P(n)"$.  So it suffices to show that it fails for composites $ab,\ a,b>1.\,$ And should be $n > 1$ since $1$ is not prime (by most conventions)

Comment: Sometimes that property is the definition of a prime and hence that is a tautology rather than a theorem.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element